# Setting up Azure Postgre SQL environment variables causing issue in connecting database from PGAdmin

Tags: azure-postgresql

I am using an open source platform to customize my application which runs using postgre SQL. From local it is working fine and when I try to connect with Azure Postgre SQL it is asking for some security keys and those are not available.

My main issue is how to create environment variables of azure postgres and how to overcome the key issues which is causing connection error.

Answer (score 0):

Some times the issue will raise regarding tokens.

Check the following steps:

1. Create Azure Postgres Server on azure platform

a. Create a resource group on your name

b. Create Postgres server like mentioned below

[image]

Here, for testing purposed, created one single server

c. Create the administrative settings like server name and password

[image]

Make a note of the server name, admin username and password.

d. By default we can keep the database name as "***postgres***"

2. Go to PGAdmin -> right click on the server
3. Choose the connection option
4. Mention all the credentials which you used to create a DB.
5. To test whether the credentials are working or not. Create a JUMP server on azure platform and use PGAdmin on that. Once it is working there, it will connect your database to azure from local.

Comment: Thanks for the procedure. Can you please show the procedure of creating a jump server as well as connecting using PGAdmin. as screens are not available in your answer.